# How to group bash command into one function?

Tags: linux, shell

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to run a sequence of commands on that file, so for example

```
ls * | xargs (cat - | calculateforfile)
```

I want to run `(cat | calculateforthisfile)` on each of the file separately. So basically, how to group a list of commands as if it is one single function?

Comment: How about `for x in *; do cat $x | calculateforfile; done` ?

Comment: shouldn't xargs do that? what is the current output when using xargs?

Comment: if your method has a problem then the fix is easy, `ls * | xargs -I file (cat file | calculateforfile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use xargs. Just use a loop. You also don't need to use `cat`. Just redirect its input with the file.

```
for A in *; do
    calculateforfile < "$A"
done
```

As a single line:

```
for A in *; do calculateforfile < "$A"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `xargs` solution for this (for example find command)

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -I % cat %
```

This will cat all the files found under current directory that end in `.txt`
The `-I` option is the key there

Comment: well if you used `find` I guess using `-exec` would be more logical, instead of passing it to a 2nd program, `find -name "*.txt" -exec "blah blah" {} \;`  where `{}` is the file in each loop

Comment: I was thinking to show the use of `xargs`. This way the input can be anything, `find` was just there to illustrate the input for cat

Comment: What if I want to run (cat fileinthelist | calculateforfile) ? and what are % symbol for? I cannot find it in man page.

Comment: Not sure what you want to say by _calculateforfile_, but you can just pipe next command normally. So `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -I % cat % | next_command` will find all files ending in .txt, and xargs will feed them one by one to cat command. Pipe after that works normally same as you would write `cat input.txt | next_command` The `%` there means that xargs will replace the next occurrence of `%` with the input from standard input (in this case the find command, can be also input from `ls` etc). The sign `%` can also be anything, ie. `$` or `!` if you wish, the key is `-I`

Comment: The difference is that next_command will receive the concatenated outputs from the cat command. I just want to run cat file | calculateforfile on each file separately. this could work if I can somehow put the filename in the middle of the string.

Comment: Hmm, let me see if I understood correctly. Command `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -I % sh -c 'cat "%" | wc -l > "%.out"'` will now run `cat file | wc -l` on each file, and output will also be separately saved to **inputfilename.out** So if I understood correctly, that would also run _calculateforfile_ for each input separately

Comment: @julumme, this does work. it is can also better in the sense that i can now sort my list of file in a certain way before run line by line. I don't know how to do that for the current solution. Very nice, thank you.

Comment: @user40129 Good to hear! How about voting the reply up, even if you have selected one answer already? Thanks ;)